# Why this IF NOT EXISTS statement is not ok?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

I'm trying to create a table but it keeps giving me error and I'm not able to figure out the problem even after checking the manual
That's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1
(ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_cI NOT NULL,
VALUE INT(11) NOT NULL,
ATTACHMENT TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL)
```

Comment: What is the exact error here?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: [works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2ca5540cf49917fa8ea59c054a89a098)

Comment: Note that while not yet reserved, value is now a listed keyword

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table1 ( ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(255) C' at line 1

Comment: Please add all clarification (like the error message, and your debugging attempts) to the question by editing it

Comment: What version of MariaDB or MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using a different word from VALUE. It is already defined as keyword